# Pass JSON data from Flask to JavaScipt in the template

Tags: javascript, json, flask, post

I'm trying to pass a list in the form a JSON from my flask server into my HTML so that it can be displayed using p5.js, but I can't get the data to pass over

```html
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, url_for
import json
from random import randint
app = Flask(__name__)

COLUMNS = 8
ROWS = 8
NUMBER_OF_TILES = 7

def build_board():
    #Setting all elements to 1 initially
    board = [[1]*COLUMNS for i in range(ROWS)]
    #Creating a random board with zero matches to begin
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLUMNS):
            board[r][c] = randint(1, NUMBER_OF_TILES)
            while (r>0 and board[r][c] == board[r - 1][c]) or (c > 0 and board[r][c] == board[r][c - 1]):
                board[r][c] = randint(1, NUMBER_OF_TILES) 
    return board  

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.dumps(build_board())
        return render_template('index.html', data=data)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

So this is the flask side and then the html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/p5.js')}}"></script>
    
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type='submit' value="Start Game" >
    </form>
    <script type='application/javascript'>
    var json = {data}
    var array = JSON.parse(json)
```

Theres more below but its not relevent to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering a variable in the Jinja template, you should use double curly brackets. Also, remember to use the `tojson` filter ([doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters)) to turn your data into JSON format for Javascript in the template:

```
var json = {{ data|tojson }}
```